# Accessing element from click event in jquery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, widget

I am trying to make a custom widget that creates tabs .But the problem Im facing is ,I have a click event defined on clicking on one of the tabs but I am unable to access the attributes associated with that tab element (like myid="summarytab")

Here is a code snippet for the same
jquery.tabs.js

```
$.widget('ui.tabs', {


    options: {


    },
    _create: function() {

        alert('attaching')

        var me = this

        me._on('td', {
            click: "_selectedTab"
        })

    },

    _selectedTab: function(el) {

        alert("coming" + el.attr('goto'))
    },

    _destroy: function() {

    }

});
```

jstChking.html

```
    <table id="tabs-container" goto="summary">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="a-detail-menu">
        <td myid="summary" goto="summary" class="selected"> 
            <i class="fa fa-bank deco"></i> 
            Summary 
        </td>

        <td goto="applicability" myid="applicabilityTab" >
            <i class="fa fa-tags deco"></i> 
            Applicability
        </td>

        <td goto="assessments" myid="assessmentTab">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o deco"></i> 
            Assessments
        </td>
        <td class="ignore"></td><td class="ignore"></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>    


<div class="a-section summary" >
    <h2>HTML Markup for these tabs</h2>
    content1
  </div>
  <div class="a-section applicability" style="display:none">
    <h2>JS for these tabs</h2>
    content2
  </div>
  <div class="a-section assessments"  style="display:none">
    <h2>CSS Styles for these tabs</h2>
    content3
  </div>
```

The idea is to hide all tabs and show the one that is clicked.I am trying to do that in jquery using the goto="xyz" and and show only that div. Now when i m trying to make in widget then i m not getting the attribute.Also if u have any suggestions ,that would be welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your click event?

Comment: me._on('td', {
            click: "_selectedTab"
        })
 are u asking about this.
if so i m looking for a DOM object like say el or element using which i can access the value of goto="xyz"

Comment: we can do it like this also
me.element.find('td').on('click',function(el){
    alert(el.attr('goto'))
})
only thing no el element is there

Comment: And where you pass the **el** parameter?

Comment: The first argument of a click handler is the `Event` object. Use `event.target` to get the `HTMLElement` that was clicked. Or, since you're using jQuery's binders, use `this`.

Comment: ok i'll try with that